# Generators in group $Z^*_{p}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

show that $g=2$ is a generator of group $Z^*_{19}$

Can anyone explain me how i can show in this example and generally that an element is a generator in a group?

Comment: @GiantTortoise1729, That's actually not good enough.  The fact that $(2,19) = 1$ simply implies that $2 \in \mathbb{Z}_{19}^\times$.  It doesn't mean it generates.  For instance, in $\mathbb{Z}_7^\times$, $2$ has order $3$ as $2^3 = 8 \equiv 1$.

Comment: @MarcusM Yes I was wrong.

Comment: For general case, you might find it hard if you google 'discrete logarithm problem'.

Comment: The "lengthy" way is to find the powers of $2$ modulo $19$. You will get $18$ different ones. There is a useful and not hard theorem that if $p$ is a prime, and $a^{(p-1)/q}\not\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ for every prime divisor $q$ of $p-1$, then $a$ is a generator. So all we need to do is to check that $2^9\not\equiv 1\pmod{19}$ and $2^6\not\equiv 1\pmod{19}$.

Answer (score 4):

We know that $\mathbb{Z}_{19}^\times = 18$, and that $2$ generates a subgroup, $H$.  By Lagrange's theorem, the order of $H$ must divide $18$, so we must have $|H| \in \{1,2,3,6,9,18\}$.  We have \begin{align}
2^1 &= 2 \neq 1\\
2^2 &= 4 \neq 1\\
2^3 &= 8 \neq 1\\
2^6 &= 64 \equiv 7 \neq 1\\
2^9 &= 2^6 \cdot 2^3 \equiv 7 \cdot 8 = 56 \equiv 18 \neq 1.
\end{align}

Thus, $|H| \neq 1,2,3,6,9$ so we must have $|H| = 18$, i.e. $2$ generates.

Comment: What's the group $\mathbb{Z}_{19}^{\times}$?

Comment: It's the multiplicative group of numbers coprime to $19$ where multiplication is taken mod $19$.

Comment: why we not calculate and $2^{18}$ like the others?

Comment: No need to, as it's the only option left.

Answer (score 0):

In general, to show that an element $g$ is a generator of a group, you need to show that every element in the group is some power of $g$.

In your case here, we know that $|\mathbb{Z}_{19}^*|=18$ and the order of an element divides the order of the group, so it suffices to check that $2^2=4\neq 1$, $2^3=8\neq 1$, $2^6=13\neq 1$, and $2^9=18\neq 1$. Therefore, $o(2)=18$, so the powers of 2 give 18 distinct elements in the group, which are all the elements.